# Social network notifications (web socket + service worker)

Tags: websocket, push-notification, notifications, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Long story short; is Facebook web application or any other social network web app handling in two different ways the in-app notifications(through web socket) and the push notification(through service worker)?
Is this statement correct?

I'm developing a web platform (social network alike) and I'm looking for a smart way to handle notifications (push notification and in app notification), NOT displaying, which is quite straight forward.

To be more clear I mean "in-app notification" those appearing in the upper right corner of the web app (usually) and displayed with fancy js or whatever, and I mean "push notification" those showed by the browser through the Notification API based on Push API and service worker.

Comment: Try socket.io https://socket.io/

Comment: Right now I already use socket.io, but I use also service worker for the push notification. I'm wondering if there is any way to use only one technology and get both type of notification, and user experience. What is the common approach to do it?

Comment: I didn't  get why you are using both. Socket io can be used to push notifications as well

Comment: Because with the service worker the push notification are like native notification in smartphone app. Even when you close your website they keep showing up. Does socket.io handle this behaviour?

Comment: Socket io can be used for communication, ie to establish a persistent connection (using web socket)

Comment: You need to use socket io on server to push notifications to client and use socket io on client to establish persistent connection with the server, subscribe to notification and when there is a notification, you can do a callback to display this

Comment: Just check if your service worker allows you to establish persistent connection (web socket) with a server